# Android browser: Is it possible to have a custom zoom level for my web page?

Tags: android, browser, zooming

I have a web page that displays on the Android and I would like to make the android not recreate the 1000+ pixel wide layout that is typical My layout will work well with only 300px or less. How can I tell this to the Android Browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the new `viewport` argument;

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=300">
```

also see http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html